# if statement not returning the correct elements on retrieving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in `FirebaseDatabase` which looks like this:

```
app
 -child1
   -uniqueId1
     -pId1
     -lId1
   -uniqueId2
     -pId2
     -lId2
   -uniqueId3
     -pId3
     -lId3
   -uniqueId4
     -pId4
     -lId4
   -uniqueId5
     -pId5
     -lId5
   -uniqueId6
     -pId6
     -lId6
 -child2
   -uniqueIdA1
     -uniqueId7
     -uniqueId8
     -uniqueId9
     -uniqueId10
     -uniqueId11
     -uniqueId1
     -uniqueId2
     -uniqueId3
     -uniqueId4
     -uniqueId5
```

I'm retrieving `child1`'s data like this:

```
public void fMethod(final String fID, final String blackListedId) {
        mDatabase.child("child1").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
                    String pID = profile.getPID();
                    String lID = profile.getLID();
                    if (!pID.trim().equals(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId().trim())) {
                        if (pID.trim().equals(fID.trim())) {
                            if (!lID.trim().equals(blackListedId.trim())) {
                            // populate the view with elements which meet this condition/requirement

                            String listingID = profile.getlID();
                            Log.d("LISTING_IDS", listingID);

                            } else {
                                Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null1");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null2");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null3");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null4");
                }
            }
            ...
            ...
            ...
    }
```

and `child2`'s data like this:

```
public void fData(final String fID) {

        mDatabase.child("child2").child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String blackListedId = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        fMethod(fID, blackListedId);
                    }
                } else {
                    fMethod(fID, "");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and then in another code I'm retrieving `fID`s and calling `fData()` method there.

I logged all the ids I'm getting from the database:

```
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId1
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId2
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId3
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId4
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
D/LISTING_IDS: uniqueId5
```

Here's `Profile.java` file's code: https://gist.github.com/HammadNasir/a196bcdc6dccbf69657fca528443e680

The problem is that in `fMethod()`'s if statement the condition is `!lID.trim().equals(blackListedId.trim()` so, as you can see in database, I should get all the `uniqueId`s under `child1` except `uniqueId3` and `uniqueId7` because these 2 are present in `child2` too but instead I'm getting all the `uniqueId`s except `uniqueId3` and `uniqueId7` twice and `uniqueId3` and `uniqueId7` once.

Another thing to note is that when I'm making that condition as `lID.trim().equals(blackListedId.trim()`, I'm getting only the 2 ids which match this requirement, i.e, `uniqueId3` and `uniqueId7` and if `child2` has only 1 id under `uniqueId11` then I'm getting all the `uniqueId`s except the one in here but having 2 or more ids is causing the problem.

I hope you got my problem. I tried my best to explain it with the least possible code.

Why `!lID.trim().equals(blackListedId.trim()` is returning unexpected ids and how can I get only the ids which meet this condition?

Comment: @Ibrahim aren't you familiar with Firebase?

Comment: Well i think your case doesn't depend on firebase skills, it's depend more on debug skills, try debug on values and check for you conditions, i'm sure that's the fastest solution.

Comment: Log everything you fetch from the server. Then post your logcat with the code.

Comment: @IshaanKumar logging all the data and posting it will be a huge work and that's why I have posted one of the elements of the dataset, i.e., `ids` which will give an idea about all the elements. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: @IshaanKumar please reply

Comment: i am not able to see any log command in your code

Comment: @IshaanKumar it is there.. see below the line `// populate the view with elements which meet this condition/requirement`.

Comment: Log everything fID, blacklisted ID, AccessToken. Then compare them. You will find what is wrong. Currently, you are just logging the result

Comment: @HammadNasir Is the value of lId is equal to uniqueId of child1 like lId1 = uniqueId1?

Comment: @MohammadAdil yes

Comment: can you please post the java code for Profile.class

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please see the edited question

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please reply

Answer (score 0):

The addListenerForSingleValueEvent for child 2 will always be called twice - once when you set it up and second when it has read all the data. So when it is called the first time, it ends up calling `fMethod(fID, "")` which is where you are getting all IDs from Child 1 including 3 and 7. But next time when it calls it, it is doing fine as you describe it. So if you remove the `"else"` condition from your child2 `ValueEventListener`, I think it should work fine.

Let me know if I understood your question and answered it. If not, feel free to explain more details.

Comment: No, Abhishek. That's not happening. I added a `log` statement in `else` code and it hasn't get called.